# Delete consecutive lines in CSV with duplicate values in one field, but keep the last line

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a long CSV file with two columns, which includes runs of consecutive duplicates like this:

```
...
1500,1533
1554,1678
1554,1703
1554,1728
1593,1766
...
```

I need to delete all of these duplicates except for the last one - so the output for the example above would be:

```
...
1500,1533
1554,1728
1593,1766
...
```

Also I need to keep the rest of the lines in the file in their original order.

I tried `tac file.csv | sort -k1,1 -r -u -t,`

but this did not give the desired result, and sort based functions messed up my line order.

Comment: Did you forget to specify the sort delimiter `-t,`? Also you will need to `tac` the result to get the desired output.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for noticing that, I will edit the question! Unfortunately I still get the duplicates though.

Comment: you need to drop the `-r` from the `sort`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '$!N;/\(.*,\).*\n\1/!P;D' infile
```

`N` means there are always two consecutive lines in the pattern space and `sed` `P`rints the first one of them only if the first field in that line is not the same as the first field in the second line. Then `D` removes the first line from the pattern space and restarts the cycle.

---

Another way with [`gnu datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) (assuming your file is sorted as `datamash` requires sorted input):

```
datamash -t ',' -g 1 last 2 <infile
```

This `g`roups the `,` delimited input by `1`st field, printing only the `last` value (from `2`nd column) of each group.

---

If your file isn't sorted `datamash` can sort it via `-s`:

```
datamash -t ',' -s -g 1 last 2 <infile
```

but that means the initial order of lines will not be preserved. So this might not do what you want. In that case you could use `sed`/`awk`/`perl` etc...

Comment: Thank you very much @don_crissti - I like your sed solution, so I will accept that as an answer (concise and does the job)

Answer (score 2):

And an alternative awk:

```
 awk -F, 'NR==1{old=$0;check=$1}NR>1 && $1 != check {print old}{old=$0;check=$1}END{print old}' knovice
1500,1533
1554,1728
1593,1766
```

Comment: Any reason you chose `$1 !~ check` instead of `$1 != check` ?

Comment: Nope ... call that a mistake =}

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `awk` approach (thanks [@Glenn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265540/delete-consecutive-lines-in-csv-with-duplicate-values-in-one-field-but-keep-the/265551?noredirect=1#comment459509_265551)):

```
 tac file | awk -F, 'awk -F, '!seen[$1]++' | tac
```

The `-F,` sets the delimiter. In `awk`, the default action when an expression evaluates to true is to print the current line. `!seen[$1]` will be true when the first field doesn't exist in the array `seen`. However, since we are also creating it with `seen[$1]++`, that will only be false the 1st time it is seen. The result is that only the first of the duplicates will be printed.

Since the script above will keep the first and not the last of each run of duplicates, the two `tac` calls are an ugly hack to reverse the order and make it keep the last. Since there are two, the final order will be unchanged.

Comment: But that prints the first of the lines with the repeats, not the last ...

Comment: @tink ah, I was wondering why you'd made yours so complex. Now I see :) Thanks, I fixed it with a couple of `tac`s but yours is better now that I understand the question.

Comment: `tac file | awk -F, '!seen[$1]++' | tac` is what I would have written

Comment: @glennjackman d'oh, of course! Much nicer, thanks. I'm on mobile now but I'll add that in when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (`mlr`) to get the last out of each group while grouping by the first field:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N tail -n 1 -g 1 file
1500,1533
1554,1728
1593,1766
```

Note that you could get the last two by simply changing `tail -n 1` to `tail -n 2` in the above command.