# remove sequential lines that begins with the same pattern using awk or sed

Tags: sed, awk

I want to remove the sequential lines that begins with the same pattern "CREATE CURRENT" using sed or awk for example if have the folowwing file:

```
CREATE CURRENT = 'aaaa' ;
CREATE CURRENT = 'bbbb' ;
CREATE CURRENT = 'aaaa' ;
CREATE CURRENT = 'dddd' ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 1 ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 1-1
CREATE CURRENT = 'cccc' ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 2 ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 2-2
```

the result would be like

```
CREATE CURRENT = 'dddd' ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 1 ;   
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 1-1 
CREATE CURRENT = 'cccc' ;
THIS IS a PARAGRAPH 2
THIS IS a PARAGRAPH 2-2 ;
```

Comment: This is just a [particular case of a more general question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265540). Anyway, with `sed` you would simply change the pattern: `sed '$!N;/\(CREATE CURRENT\).*\n\1/!P;D'  infile`

Comment: @don-crissti yes it's working you have to post this answer

Answer (score 0):

try

```
awk '{ if ( $1 "x" != before "x" ) print ; before=$1 ; } ' file
```

where

- `$1 "x" != before "x"` test with previous value of first field
- `before "x"` whith implicit string concat allow for uninitialized first before value
- `before=$1` remember previous $1 value.

Update with OP's edit:

```
awk 'BEGIN {cc=0 } 
    /CREATE CURRENT/ { if ( !cc++) print ; else next ;} 
    {cc=0; print ;} '
```

- consecutives lines with `CREATE CURRENT` are printed only once
- other lines reinitalize `cc` value
- you can add new line within `' '` or put all in one line.

Comment: I edited my question, the line that shoud be removed if they are sequential are the ones that begin with  'CREATE CURRENT'

Answer (score 0):

Open it up in `vi` and you can use:

```
:%s/\(\(\_^CREATE CURRENT\).*\n\)\(\2.*\n\)*/\1/g
```

This may leave an extra newline at the end of the file if you have `CREATE CURRENT` lines at the end of the file.  If so, you can delete the extra line with `:$d`.

If you're all happy with it, save it with `:x`, or discard changes and exit using `:q!`

---

To keep the last of each set of duplicates instead of the first, use:

```
:%s/\(\(\_^CREATE CURRENT\).*\n\)\+\(\2.*\n\)/\3/g
```

Comment: thanks it's working but it kept the first line I want to keep the last occurence of the duplicate line I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I tried this sed and it's working

```
sed '/^CREATE CURRENT/ { :a $! { N; /\nCREATE CURRENT/ { s/.*\n//; ba; }; }; }' file
```

here's the result

```
CREATE CURRENT = 'dddd' ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 1 ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 1-1
CREATE CURRENT = 'cccc' ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 2 ;
THIS IS A PARAGRAPH 2-2
```